# PHP convert date and time from UTC to Europe/London

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following date string in the following format:

```
$received = "Tue, 15 Sep 2015 12:35:03 +0000 (UTC)";
```

I would like to convert this to the Europe/London timezone as the actual time is supposed to read 13:35:03

Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you want to accept my answer? If the resulted output is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a new Timezone maybe you want to set this dynamically then set the new dateTime from database:

```
$received = "Tue, 15 Sep 2015 12:35:03 +0000 (UTC)";

$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$date = new DateTime($received);
$date->setTimezone($tz);
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

The output is:

```
13:35:03
```

Answer (score 1):

The current/correct way to do this:

```
$received = "Tue, 15 Sep 2015 12:35:03 +0000 (UTC)";
$date = new DateTime($received);

echo $date->format('c'); // 2015-09-15T12:35:03+00:00

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

echo $date->format('c'); // 2015-09-15T13:35:03+01:00
```

You build the DateTime object from the string, then change the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you need to create DateTime object then convert the time zone
when you display after you change the time zone then it will display correct time.

```
$t = new DateTime($received);
date_timezone_set($t, timezone_open('Europe/London'));
echo date_format($t, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```